# Analytics cross domain iFrame tracking with Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-sdk

[IFrame tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#iframe) has never been a problem while using Google Analytics directly inserted on to the page.
But now i started using Google Tag Manager to administrate scripts, i got an problem.

```
function addGaIframe(ua_code, opt_hash) {

    console.log("Add Ga");

    //Check UA
    console.log(ua_code);

    return function(tracker) {

        //Check Tracker
        console.log(tracker);

        window.linker = window.linker || new window.gaplugins.Linker(tracker);
        ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
        ifrm.style.width = 100+"%";
        ifrm.style.border = "none";
        ifrm.frameborder = "0";
        ifrm.allowtransparency = "true";
        ifrm.id = "iframe_xx";

        ifrm.src = window.linker.decorate("https://xxxxxxx.com/ua="+ua_code, opt_hash);

        document.getElementById('iframe').appendChild(ifrm);

    };
}
```

When i look in the console i can see that the `tracker` is undefined

[image]

Normally the tracker is an object like :

[image]

I hope that someone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just add, in "Fields to Set", `allowLinker : 1` and add the domains which the iframes uses under `Auto Link Domains`.
It worked :)